# how to display image from folder in glade in c programming?

Tags: c, glade

I am new to glade . i want to display image from folder a folder . i wrote a c program but not enough to reach destination .

```
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
 void 
 on_window_destroy (GtkObject *object, gpointer user_data)
 {
 gtk_main_quit ();
 }

 int
  main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 GtkBuilder      *builder; 
 GtkWidget       *window;

 gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
 builder = gtk_builder_new ();
 gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "image.xml", NULL);
 window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window"));
 gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);
 g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder));
 gtk_widget_show (window); 
 GError *error = NULL;
 GdkPixbuf *pix = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file ("logo1.png", &error);
 gtk_widget_imageshow(pix) ;
 }
```

is it possible to refresh the image  ?  thanks